# yeoman angular fullstack -modal

Tags: angularjs, yeoman-generator-angular

For my application I would like show a modal window when a user click on the login button in the header. I tried the example using angular- ui bootstrap standalone and it is working fine.

But when I integrate with yeoman-angular-fullstack I could not get the modal.Also it is not showing any error in grunt test and in my developer tool.
please help to fix this

Comment: Make sure grunt isn't removing the angular bootstrap resource from your index.html file, it is possible it's not getting included in the build

Comment: I checked index.html and it is showing angular bootstrap.The modal alone is not working. It redirecting me to new blank window. I tried grunt mingle  to false .How to check whether modal directive is compatible with my yeoman angular stack. I googled a lot and tried all fix. But nothing working out. the below is my angular bootstrap versions 
    "angular": ">=1.2.*",
     "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10"

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your index.html and your page that has the modal

Answer (score 0):

so, this is what I have done:

**in your navbar.html:**

```
<li ng-hide="nav.isLoggedIn()" ui-sref-active="active"><a ng-click=openSignUp() href>Sign up</a></li>
```

**in your navbar.controller.js:**

```
 $scope.openSignUp = function(){
      signupTemplate.openSignUpModal();
 };
```

I'm using a created service called *signupTemplate*, that can be usefull.

**In my service signupTemplate:**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('signupTemplate',['$uibModal', function ($uibModal) {

    self.dataForModal={
        // yourData: here,
    };


    this.openSignUpModal = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true
            template: '<your-component modal-data="$ctrl.modalData"></your-component>'
            controller: ['modalData', function(modalData) {
                var $ctrl=this;
                $ctrl.modalData = modalData;
            }],
            controllerAs:'$ctrl',
            resolve: {
                modalData: self.dataForModal
            }
        }; 
    }]);
```

To send the data from your parent where the modal is called to your modal, you have to put your data in dataForModal.

And to close and access your data in your component, you have to bind it.

**in yourComponent.component.js**

```
bindings:{
    modalData:'<',
    $close: '&',
}
```